# Java Confusing Ternary Sonar Violation Issue

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, sonarqube, sonarlint

Sonar reported Confusing Ternary violation against the below code:

```
package com.example.dto;

import java.util.Date;

public class ShiftTemplateUserDTO {
  private Date breakStartTime;
  private Date breakEndTime;
  
  public Date getBreakStartTime() {
    return breakStartTime != null ? new Date(breakStartTime.getTime()) : null;
  }

  public void setBreakStartTime(Date breakStartTime) {
    this.breakStartTime = breakStartTime != null ? new Date(breakStartTime.getTime()) : null;
  }

  public Date getBreakEndTime() {
    return breakEndTime != null ? new Date(breakEndTime.getTime()) : null;
  }

  public void setBreakEndTime(Date breakEndTime) {
    this.breakEndTime = breakEndTime != null ? new Date(breakEndTime.getTime()) : null;
  }
}
```

I tried updating the code to add if/else condition but still Sonar is complaining about the same rule, what am I doing wrong?

```
  public Date getBreakStartTime() {
    if (breakStartTime != null) {
      return new Date(breakStartTime.getTime());
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public void setBreakStartTime(Date breakStartTime) {
    if (breakStartTime != null) {
      this.breakStartTime = new Date(breakStartTime.getTime());
    } else {
      this.breakStartTime = null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Apart from the solution, you may also want to drop this check in the setter and just store the value, since you extract time in the getter anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I removed the check in the setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use negated conditions in ternary operators.
Try replacing this:

```
return breakStartTime != null ? new Date(breakStartTime.getTime()) : null;
```

with this:

```
return breakStartTime == null ? null : new Date(breakStartTime.getTime());
```

---

The same applies to your `if-else` logic.
Replace this:

```
if (breakStartTime != null) {
  return new Date(breakStartTime.getTime());
} else {
  return null;
}
```

with this:

```
if (breakStartTime == null) {
  return null;
} else {
  return new Date(breakStartTime.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Even after this Sonar is still showing me same Null pointer bug.

Answer (score 2):

Sonar doesn't like "un-equal" comparisons. It wants you to write `foo == null ? null : ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You also might consider that instead of doing this:

```
public Date getBreakStartTime() {
    return breakStartTime != null ? new Date(breakStartTime.getTime()) : null;
}
```

You just do this:

```
public Date getBreakStartTime() {
    return breakStartTime;
}
```

In your current code, if the Date object is not null, you are constructing a new Date object with the same time value as the original Date value.  That results in effectively the same object.  You might be concerned about immutability. Is that really a concern for you?